# Is there really a strong CP problem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, cp-violation, axion

The strong CP problem is considered one of the biggest unsolved physics problems. A nonvanishing value of $\theta$ in QCD $\theta$-term violates CP-symmetry. A primary strong CP violating observable is the electric dipole moment of the neutron $d_n$. The current observed upper bound of $d_n$ is extremely small, which is commonly taken as an indication that $\theta$ is anomalously small, hence the strong CP problem.

However, [a new preprint on arXiv by Schierholz](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.13508), *Absence of strong CP violation*,  published today basically claims that there is no strong CP problem: It turns out that the electric dipole moment of the neutron $d_n$ could not be used to detect the CP violating $\theta$. In other words, $d_n$ could be extremely small while $\theta$ is NOT small.

We know that there are several proposed solutions to solve the strong CP problem. The most well-known is Peccei–Quinn theory, involving new pseudoscalar particles called axions. If the above new paper is correct, all the efforts of "solving" CP problem would be a waste of time!

My question: Could the electric dipole moment of the neutron $d_n$ be used to effectively detect the CP violating $\theta$? If not, then is there really a strong CP problem?

Comment: Is your question basically to have us read the paper and tell you if it is correct or not?

Comment: @octonion, changed the question at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I'll restrict myself to answer

> Blockquote My question: Could the electric dipole moment of the neutron $d_n$ be used to effectively detect the CP violating $\theta$? If not, then is there really a strong CP problem?

In [these lectures on the CP Problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.02669) or [this SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362444/why-and-how-does-the-term-frac-theta32-pi2f-mu-nu-a-tildef-mu-nu-a?rq=1) you can see how you can relate the value of of the theta angle $\theta$ to the value of the neutron eDM. *A priori* it should be possible to obtain a similar result for the proton but, as far as I know, we mostly focus on the neutron eDM because it is easier to measure. **So, even if there were no $d_n$, you could still have other similar magnitudes that are not null**.

But OK, let's imagine that there is some mechanism that suppresses all QCD eDMs (and other CP-violating quantities) without that requiring a non-null $\bar{\theta}$. Could we still have a CP problem? Well, it could still be that QCD does not violate CP-symmetry, but we would not be able to measure it experimentally, so we would lose all experimental justification to search for reasons that drive $\bar{\theta}$ to be small! This doesn't mean that axions, or whatever other solution to the Strong CP problem, don't exist. **We would have just lost the biggest reason to believe they exist** (there are others, as we think axions might be cold dark matter, see [this again](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.02669)).

Just as a side note, in the preprint you're mentioning, the author is only proposing another solution to the CP problem, albeit it involves only reducing the impact of the value of $\theta$ on the value of $d_n$, and thus proposing another explanation to why $d_n$ is so small. So he is not "removing" the CP problem, he is just (attempting to) solve it.

Note 2: There are other physical implications of the theta term, like a $\theta$-dependent vacuum energy (see Vafa-Witten theorem), but I am not sure whether they can be experimentally tested. Maybe someone else can add on this.